# Retrieve Page Layout by SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, page-layout

I have a few `page layouts` assigned to record types in a custom object.
How to retrieve page layouts as meta-data by command `sfdx force:source:pull`?
Right now my source tracking doesn't see any changes connected with `page layouts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Record Type Assignments are retrieved by Profile. Any changes you make to such assignments will be in the profile metadata.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles on message that is something like this:
*Entity of type 'Layout' named 'Account.Account_Layout' cannot be found*
then instead of a dot after the name of an object like "Account" there shoud be "-". It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Page layout using below command.

**Standard Objects**

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:ObjectAPIName.PageLayoutName"

Example : sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:Account.Account_Layout"

**Custom Objects**

You can retrieve the page layout of a custom object with the below command:

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:customObject__ObjectName-Page Layout Name"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I try your method but I got `No results found`. In table of details is shown `unpackaged/package.xml Entity of type 'Layout' named 'Account.Account_Layout' cannot be found`
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @hsd If you are trying to pull the page layout for a custom object, something like the following should work: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "Layout:customObject__ObjectName-Page Layout Name"`